# mat dialog and a mat table shows a line below the heading

Tags: angular, dialog, mat-table, mat-dialog

The `mat-table` in a mat dialog shows a line below the heading. Has any one faced this and how do I fix this?

[image: Please see this image for the line that shows up below the heading]

Below is the code

```html
<h2 mat-dialog-title>dialog title</h2>
<mat-dialog-content class="mat-typography">
    <div class="bottom-box">
        <!-- Add expansion panel here -->
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="data.dataSource" matSort>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="areaName">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> column 1</th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row "> test data </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="fixture">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> column 2 </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row "> {{ row.fValue }} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns; "></tr>

            <!-- Row shown when there is no matching data. -->
            <tr class=" mat-row " *matNoDataRow>
                <td class="mat-cell " colspan=5>{{ noItemsFound }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10]"></mat-paginator>
    </div>
</mat-dialog-content>
<mat-dialog-actions align="end">
    <button mat-raised-button mat-dialog-close color="primary" (click)="onConfirmClick()">{{confirmText}}</button>
</mat-dialog-actions>
```

Answer (score 1):

Mark 'autoFocus: false' in dialog opening config.
This underline is coming due to dialog autofocus on first element.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem. No idea why this is happening since it does not happen on every time I open a table.

I used this in my css as a workaround:

```
::ng-deep .mat-sort-header-container {
  border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: thank you.. But I am guessing there should be a better way. It has been intermittent for me as well. Appears sometimes, not always.